# Can you help me Add this behavior in angular-js form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

Fields:

1. field `f1`: file upload input field(I am using a custom angular directive )
2. field `f2`: Comments text-area field

Now, there is a radio button "yes" and another "no"

Pseudocode -

```
on selecting "yes":
{
    "f1" appears and is a required field
    and 
    "f2" stays invisible and disabled and not a required field
}
while
    on selecting "no":
        vice versa
```

final condition is that the submit button disables in case I dont upload a file on selecting "yes"
or if I dont fill the comment field on selecting "no"

Note : Just to be clear....either `f1` is required , enabled and visible, or `f2` is.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="check" value="yes">yes
<input type="radio" ng-model="check" value="no">no

<input type="file" ng-disabled="check == 'no'" ng-required="check == 'yes'" ng-show="check == 'yes'">
<input type="textarea" ng-disabled="check == 'yes'" ng-required="check == 'no'" ng-show="check == 'no'">

<input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$error.required" value="submit">
```

Comment: `ng-if` and `ng-required` should do it i believe.

Comment: This site is about answers not writing your code for you. You must show what you have attempted and that you have attempted to put reasonable self research into the problem. At that time ask a question if needed but don't just ask people to write your code for you.

Comment: I'm sorry man....but I have given my part too...and when I inspect my page it seems to be working fine inside , in the html, but it does not reflect on the page

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon...I can not put my complete code here...its for commercial purpose and confidential

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/1257/

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.check = "yes";
}
```

Link your code to a controller that contains the value you are putting in your model. Go back and read angular docs before you start trying out.

Comment: bro your code too works like mine...the submit button is'nt getting disabled as per requirement

Comment: i was coding the same...its just I was'nt giving the radio a default value (yes or no) , giving which has solved my problem

Comment: you didnt have a form and you were checking form.error which was wrong.

Comment: no I have form tag in the complete code man...I have given here just the core part